# Highcharts - pie chart : applying curreny pipe for labelFormatter

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, legend

I am trying to create a pie chart using highcharts. For the legend I want to apply my customized pipe to show the currency. But I am not able to do that.

chart legend code

```
   legend: {
       align: 'right',
       verticalAlign: 'middle',
       layout: 'vertical',
       symbolWidth: 15,
       symbolRadius: 7,
       labelFormatter: this.formatCurrency,
       useHTML: true
   }

   formatCurrency() {
       return this.curPipe.transform(this['y'], "pipeFilter")
   }
```

For above case I am not able to access curPipe.

if I make formatCurrency  function as arrow function I am able to access my filter but not able to access chart series data using this object.

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle for this ?

Comment: Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to recreate a live example, e.g. on jsfiddle - or at least paste complete code.